# Java weblogic error with Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, weblogic, sftp, kerberos, weblogic-10.x

We are facing below error when trying to push some of bulk-upload using sftp from Source server to destination servers.

Back-end of this application running on weblogic.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Configuration was registered that can handle the configuration named com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate
    at com.bea.common.security.jdkutils.JAASConfiguration.getAppConfigurationEntry(JAASConfiguration.java:124)
    at sun.security.jgss.LoginConfigImpl.getAppConfigurationEntry(LoginConfigImpl.java:139)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:243)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:499)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSUtil.login(GSSUtil.java:244)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getTicket(Krb5Util.java:136)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:328)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:325)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:128)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:106)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:172)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:209)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:195)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:162)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.jgss.GSSContextKrb5.init(GSSContextKrb5.java:129)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthGSSAPIWithMIC.start(UserAuthGSSAPIWithMIC.java:135)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:419)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:210)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JAAS configuration file? If you do, then you probably have old format of "initiate" section - com.sun.security.jgss.initiate, note that it's missing ".krb5". It should be com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate.

Or maybe the path to configuration file is incorrect in your server startup command line.